# How to compare two character vectors for near equality in R?

Tags: r, string-comparison

I have two datasets, and I want to compare the values of one column in one dataset with values of a column in another dataset. Given this is the column of the first dataset:

```
df1$names
KLERK
JAMES MEDICAL CITY
MISSION & COMMUNITY CENTER
COSTA MEDICAL CENTER
...
```

Given the column in the other dataset is:

```
df2$names
Klerk Hospital
James Medical
Mission and Community
Costa Medical
...
```

As you can see, the values are not completely equal, but for example, `KLERK` and `Klerk Hospital` are the same hospital. If I use basic R comparisons, it only gives me FALSE. I also tried to use the stri_cmp_equiv function with no success. I only have names and addresses that I can use to match, but with the address, it is the same problem. For example `1200 E Road` and `1200 East Road`. I am looking for a function or solution to compare the character values for if they are close but not completely equal. The outcome should be `TRUE`/`FALSE`. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might wanna try [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin)

Comment: In Bioinformatics, we use local alignment to fuzzy match one string to another. Maybe you will have success with the Smith-Waterman algo. If not, you need to incorporate domain knowledge like & means `and`.

Comment: Or you could some regex, split each value on spaces and see if the majority matches. (i.e. split klerk hospital then if 50% or more is equal then return TRUE else FALSE.

Comment: There is also [thefuzz](https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz) in python. You can import the dissimilarity matrix afterwards

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to compute a suitable distance metric between strings, and based on a certain similarity/disimilarity threshold assign TRUE or FALSE. In R the package [`stringdist`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html) is created for this sort of task. Before comparison I would convert all characters to lower.

```
library(stringdist)
stringdist(tolower(vec1), tolower(vec2))
#output
9  5 10  7
```

you can change the metric to the one that suits your need the best:

```
stringdist(tolower(vec1), tolower(vec2), method = "cosine")
#output
0.28730335 0.07852140 0.09548458 0.09507710
```

The function `stringsim` returns similarity:

```
stringsim(tolower(vec1), tolower(vec2))
#output
0.3571429 0.7222222 0.6153846 0.6500000
```

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = vec1, v2 = vec2)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(cosine = stringdist(tolower(df$v1), tolower(df$v2), method = "cosine"),
         decision = cosine < 0.2)
#output
                          v1                    v2     cosine decision
1                      KLERK        Klerk Hospital 0.28730335    FALSE
2         JAMES MEDICAL CITY         James Medical 0.07852140     TRUE
3 MISSION & COMMUNITY CENTER Mission and Community 0.09548458     TRUE
4       COSTA MEDICAL CENTER         Costa Medical 0.09507710     TRUE
```

There are several different methods, in addition with methods `osa` or `dl` you can set the penalty for deletion, insertion, substitution and transposition, in that order. Example (low penalty for deletion and insertion but high for substitution and transposition):

```
df %>%
  mutate(diff = stringdist(tolower(df$v1), tolower(df$v2),
                           method = "osa",
                           weight = c(0.01, 0.01, 1, 1)),
         decision = diff < 0.2)

#output
                          v1                    v2 diff decision
1                      KLERK        Klerk Hospital 0.09     TRUE
2         JAMES MEDICAL CITY         James Medical 0.05     TRUE
3 MISSION & COMMUNITY CENTER Mission and Community 0.11     TRUE
4       COSTA MEDICAL CENTER         Costa Medical 0.07     TRUE
```

EDIT: as suggested by @danlooo in the comments another option would be
to make a local string alignment and output its score. Based on the score assign a threshold to convert to logical. This can be performed with the [`Biostrings`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package available via Bioconductor (see install section in the provided link if you decide to go this raute):

```
library(Biostrings)
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  pairwiseAlignment(tolower(x[1]), tolower(x[2]), type = "overlap")@score
})
#output
17.83352 46.36715 45.78177 47.86837
```

to return the whole `pairwiseAlignment` objects:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x){
  pairwiseAlignment(tolower(x[1]), tolower(x[2]), type = "overlap")
})
#output
[[1]]
Overlap PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] klerk
subject: [1] klerk
score: 17.83352 

[[2]]
Overlap PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] james medical
subject: [1] james medical
score: 46.36715 

[[3]]
Overlap PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] mission &-- community
subject: [1] mission and community
score: 45.78177 

[[4]]
Overlap PairwiseAlignmentsSingleSubject (1 of 1)
pattern: [1] costa medical
subject: [1] costa medical
score: 47.86837
```

Just bare in mind this last code run returns S4 type of object.

data:

```
vec1 <- c("KLERK",
          "JAMES MEDICAL CITY",
          "MISSION & COMMUNITY CENTER",
          "COSTA MEDICAL CENTER")

vec2 <- c("Klerk Hospital",
          "James Medical",
          "Mission and Community",
          "Costa Medical")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution to you problem.

Basically we can use regex to determine how closely matched each string is to it's companion string. If over 50% of the individual words match then it returns true.

```
names1 <- data.frame(Name = c("KLERK", "JAMES MEDICAL CITY", "MISSION & COMMUNITY CENTER", "COSTA MEDICAL CENTER"))
names2 <- data.frame(Name = c("Klerk Hospital", "James Medical", "Mission and Community", "Cost Medical"))

names1$Name <- str_to_lower(names1$Name)
names2$Name <- str_to_lower(names2$Name)

split_names1 <- str_split(names1$Name, " ")
split_names2 <- str_split(names2$Name, " ")


str_detect(split_names1[[1]], split_names2[[1]])


my_matches <- mapply(str_detect, split_names1, split_names2)


my_func <- function(x) {
  
  ifelse(sum(x)/length(x) >= .5, T, F)
  
}

map(my_matches, my_func)


[[1]]
[1] TRUE

[[2]]
[1] TRUE

[[3]]
[1] TRUE

[[4]]
[1] TRUE
```